# finding the expected value of the largest r.v.

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a random variable representing the claims incurred by an insurance company in one year and the probability density function is as follows:

\begin{equation}
f_X(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\frac{3}{x^4} ; x>1 \\
0 ; \text { .v. }
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}

With sample size $n = 3$, calculate the expected value of the largest r.v. of incurred claims.

I did not understand how to calculate the expected value of the largest one in the distribution. How should I proceed? I calculated the expected value of the expression but I think this is not the correct answer

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic.

Answer (score 1):

Let $M = \max\{X_1,X_2,X_3 \}$, where $X_1, X_2$ and $X_3$ are independent and identically distributed by the law $f_x$ you defined in your post.

Then:

$$\mathbb{E}[Y] = \iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3} \max\{x_1,x_2,x_3 \} f_{x_1}(x_1) f_{x_2}(x_2)f_{x_3}(x_3)dx_1 dx_2 dx_3.$$

Suppose for a while that $x_1 = \max\{x_1, x_2, x_3\}$. Consider:

$$I_1 = \iiint_{D_1} x_1 f_{x_1}(x_1) f_{x_2}(x_2)f_{x_3}(x_3)dx_1 dx_2 dx_3,$$

where $D_1 = \{(x_1, x_2, x_3) : x_1 \geq \max\{x_2, x_3\}\} = \{(x_1, x_2, x_3) : x_1 \geq x_2 \wedge x_1 \geq x_3\}.$

In other words:

$$I_1 = \int_{1}^{+\infty}\int_{1}^{x_1}\int_{1}^{x_1}x_1 f_{x_1}(x_1) f_{x_2}(x_2)f_{x_3}(x_3)dx_3 dx_2 dx_1 = \\
=\int_{1}^{+\infty}\int_{1}^{x_1}x_1 f_{x_1}(x_1) f_{x_2}(x_2)\left(\int_{1}^{x_1}f_{x_3}(x_3)dx_3\right) dx_2 dx_1 = \\
=\int_{1}^{+\infty}\int_{1}^{x_1}x_1 f_{x_1}(x_1) f_{x_2}(x_2)\left(1-x_1^{-3}\right) dx_2 dx_1 = \\
=\int_{1}^{+\infty}x_1 f_{x_1}(x_1)\left(1-x_1^{-3}\right)\left(\int_{1}^{x_1} f_{x_2}(x_2) dx_2\right) dx_1 = \\
=\int_{1}^{+\infty}x_1 f_{x_1}(x_1)\left(1-x_1^{-3}\right)\left(1-x_1^{-3}\right) dx_1 = \\
=\int_{1}^{+\infty}x_1 \cdot 3 x_1^{-4}\left(1-x_1^{-3}\right)^2 dx_1 = \\
=\int_{1}^{+\infty}\left(3 x_1^{-3} - 6 x_1 ^ {-6} + 3 x_1^{-9}\right) dx_1 = \frac{27}{40}.
$$

For symmetry, $I_1 = I_2 = I_3$, and $\mathbb{E}[Y] =I_1 + I_2 + I_3 = 3I_1$. Hence:

$$\mathbb{E}[Y] = 3 \cdot \frac{27}{40} = \frac{81}{40}.$$